# Import * statement in Python

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I thought that

```
from tkinter import *
```

imports all names into my current file's namespace so that I can access all of it directly. However, I get an error on instantiating a message box:

```
messagebox.showinfo("Something")
```

Once I add

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

all works fine. I don't understand why. Didn't the first import statement already import all names in the tkinter module including messagebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

messagebox is a submodule of tkinter.
You should import module "messagebox" 
(use "import ... as ..." to make it shorter)

```
import tkinter.messagebox
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Something")
```

Or as you figured out yourself,

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Answer (score 2):

Importing a module (`tkinter`) does not automatically import submodules (`tkinter.messagebox`) unless the module do it explicitly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since messagebox is a file inside the Tkinter module, you won't be able to access it by just calling Tkinter. To import the submodules you have to call out the specific files like this:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```